# html 2 field names the same, different forms on the one page.. is this ok?

Tags: html

So I have

```
<form id="formA">
 <input id="uuid">
</form>

<form id="formB">
 <input id="uuid">
</form>
```

is this ok to have 2 field names on different forms? I'm thinking access via javascript.

Comment: Wasn't this question asked only yesterday?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same name? Yes. They can be in the same form for that matter (this is essential for radio button groups!)

Your example, however, has two elements with the same **id** which is **not** OK. An id must be unique within a document.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was thinking of accessing via a form reference, but the id should be unique on the page..

Answer (score 3):

It's okay to have two *names* that are the same, but in your example you have two *ids* that are the same, which is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

No, identical `id`s in a document are invalid. You can have multiple `name`s in different forms, though.

Answer (score 0):

David is correct from a "good programming" stand-point. By definition an "id" should be unique. However, if you HAD to have this, you could access those input nodes, you would just need to access their parent, first.

Comment: There is no almost about it. By definition an id must be unique.

Comment: very true!!! I actually was typing one thing, then decided to type something else and hit the "Add Answer" before I could take out the Almost...